# How to get resources from EmbeddedResource

Tags: c#, .net, dnlib

```
var resource = module.FindResource($"{type.Namespace}.{type.Name}.resources");

resource.Name = $"{type.Namespace}.{type.Name}.resources";

EmbeddedResource embedded = (EmbeddedResource)resource;
```

How do I access the resource images from the Embedded resource?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/3314140/5265292

Comment: Already tried that but cannot get anything out of it, don't think it would suit my needs though as I want to modify the resource(s) names.

Comment: You don't mention in your question, that you want to modify resource names. Please make sure to accurately describe your desired result in the question. I thought you want to read the resource contents, but now I don't know what you want to do at all.

Comment: I want to "get resources from Embedded Resource" so that I can modify the name(s) of them. Is it possible?

Comment: Embedded resources are part of the assembly.dll file and not meant to be changed in any aspect after creation of the assembly